# Scrapy: how can I get the content of pages whose response.status=302?

Tags: web-scraping, scrape, scrapy

I get the following log when crawling:

```
DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET http://fuyuanxincun.fang.com/xiangqing/> (referer: http://esf.hz.fang.com/housing/151__1_0_0_0_2_0_0/)
DEBUG: Scraped from <302 http://fuyuanxincun.fang.com/xiangqing/>
```

But it actually returns nothing.
How can I deal with these response with status=302?

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: Btw, Scrapy handles those automatically, if you leave it out of `handle_httpstatus_list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP status 302 means Moved Temporarily. When I do a HTTP GET request to the url http://fuyuanxincun.fang.com/xiangqing/ it show's me a HTTP 200 status. It's common that the server won't send anything after sending the 302 statuscode (altough technically sending data after a 302 is possible).

The reason why you get a HTTP 302 status can be one of the following:

1. The website does not serve it's content when a specific referer (like: http://esf.hz.fang.com/housing/151__1_0_0_0_2_0_0/) is present.
2. You didn't send the HTTP headers the server wants to see. For example like a certain User-Agent. The website can decide to reject requests without a specific header by sending a HTTP 302 status instead of a HTTP 200 status.
3. The specific IP-address you try to send the request from is excluded by the website you try to gather.

I would recommend to:

1. Make the request look like a "real" browser request (communicate similair headers).
2. Try to send the request from another IP-address.
3. Try to send the request with a (randomized) User-Agent.

---

*I did the request at UTC time 07:30:29 Wednesday, 13 May 2015, the behavior of the website could be changed in the time between your and my request.*

*Also it can be helpfull to post the full RAW HTTP request and response.*

Comment: thanks for your specific explanation, dwarf ! It really helps a lot as I knew little about HTTP.  I have used some User-Agents and IP-addresses, but I can't make sure if all my User-Agents are effective. Do you know how to test a User-Agent ?

Comment: You could try to do for example a few requests with different user-agents. And check if the HTTP respons headers/statuscode are different between requests. That's not ideal, but it could give you an indication for the potential user-agent problem.